# Boundary Tests For a Networked App

Tags: testing, networking, wireless

Besides "no connection", what other failure modes should I test for?  How do I simulate a high-latency link, an unreliable link, or all the other sorts of crazy stuff that will undoubtedly happen "in the wild"?

How about wireless applications? How do I test the performance in a less-than-ideal WL environment?

Answer (score 1):

> To add to TimK's answer, if you have a router, test pulling the upstream link on the router, this will test a bad connection without your system knowing that you lost the physical link.

Also if you plug it back in after a few seconds it's possible that the connection won't be lost*. This can simulate a very high latency.

*this depends on your ISP and your router.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Linux, try [Virtual Distributed Ethermet](http://vde.sourceforge.net/) (VDE).

VDE gives you virtualised switches/hubs and Ethernet cables. You can tune network characteristics such as latency, delay, MTU, errored bits per MB, bandwidth, duplicates, etc on individual cables - all in real time!

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to test physically pulling the cable out.  Lots of networking code will throw different exceptions in that scenario vs when the connection has just been lost.

Answer (score 0):

To add to TimK's answer, if you have a router, test pulling the upstream link on the router, this will test a bad connection without your system knowing that you lost the physical link.

Answer (score 0):

Our network/server closet is a spaghetti-mess of wires; I'm not going to walk in there and start unplugging stuff lest I hit something mission-critical.  (At least I have access to it; I'm sure many readers don't even know where their routers are.)  Similarly, both ends of the ethernet cable require a hands-and-knees adventure to reach.

I tested enabling/disabling the network adapter, and I'm going to test from my cable internet connection from home as well.  Also, I had the idea of installing Tor to create a high latency connection.

For wireless connections, I have a metal box to test what happens when the signal dies, but I notice that network connection behavior is very different depending on how I test:

- put the transmitter/reciever in a metal box
- go stand next to the microwave in the kitchen and turn it on
- go stand in a little closet which has concrete walls